# New usb wifi card on linux

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, usb

I plugged my USB wifi card and on /var/log/message I can see that new hardware has been found

```
Sep 17 16:21:34 bt kernel: [43049.422451] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 5
Sep 17 16:21:40 bt kernel: [43055.436615] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci_hcd
```

With lsusb I can see:

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 2001:3a03 D-Link Corp. DWL-G132 (no firmware) [Atheros AR5523]
```

It seems to be a driver problem. Where can I found a tutorial to install and configure (add to interface) my USB WiFi card?

------ UPDATE --------
After some try using [ndiswrapper](http://www.eracc.com/content/how-use-ndiswrapper) (I was able to install my network card but, this is the output message:

```
dmesg | grep -e rt2 -e rt3 -e wlan
[ 5318.598255] Registered led device: rt2800usb-phy0::radio
[ 5318.598282] Registered led device: rt2800usb-phy0::assoc
[ 5318.598309] Registered led device: rt2800usb-phy0::quality
[ 5318.598407] usbcore: registered new interface driver rt2800usb
[ 5321.021254] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
```

Cheers!

Comment: It is one of those cards that does not seem to have a proper driver for Linux. You can find a guide how to still get it to work using `ndiswrapper`, that uses Windows drivers to get the hardware configured. Try https://www.google.com/search?q=DWL-G132+linux+driver

Comment: Now it seems working fine but I get this message: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready

Comment: There may be a conflict of multiple drivers claiming the device or firmware not loading correctly. Make sure the firmware is available and gets loaded etc. `dmesg | grep rt2800` would be of interest. Try http://google.com/search?q=rt2800usb+wlan0:+link+is+not+ready